# How to get rid of 'log file sync' waits?

Tags: oracle, oracle10g, wait

The problem is that my database is experiencing a lot of problems with 'log file sync' session waits. The process LGWR holds about 400-450 sessions at a time, which causes a lot of performance issues.

System also shows that we reached limit of disk usage.

ASH analyzer shows the following profiling session results:
[image: profiling session results]

If you need some additional information to help (such as log buffer size, sga size or some system configuration), just let me know.

Comment: "System also shows that we reached limit of disk usage." - if by that you mean your disk I/O is saturated... that's a problem. http://orainternals.wordpress.com/2008/07/07/tuning-log-file-sync-wait-events/ has some good tips for analyzing this.

Comment: That's the result, the reason is in something else. I mean, it's not normal that log is being written to the disk that often and that much - normally we had much less I/O activity.

Answer (score 0):

The LGWR process is a write intensive I/O process, writing to the Redo Log files. Think of anything that would slow down the write process. For example, if the Redo Logs are writing to RAID5 (known for slower writes), or the datafiles exist on the same storage system causing I/O contention. Of course, more advanced storage systems may not have these problems with their own caching and distributed I/O.

Also, LGWR is asked to write upon each commit. If there is excessive small quick commits it may cause this wait event. Larger transactions will reduce pressure on the LGRW process.